# A field in a React Hook Form does not update the form state unless that field get the focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form. I have this simple form:

[A simple form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Vmu.png)

When I enter values in the "quantity "and "price" fields, the third field, "total" shows the result of multiplying them. So far, all fine.  But I have noticed that when I click the submit button the value in the "total" field does not update the data form, unless that previously it get the focus by clicking on it.
This is what I get when I don't click the "total" field:

[Showing the state form in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmvPu.png)

As you can see in the last image, the value of the "total" field is not reflected in the form state.

This is my code:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

function App() {

  const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="quantity">Quantity: </label>
          <input type="number" 
            {...register("quantity")}  
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="price">Price: </label>
          <input type="number"
            {...register("price")}
          />
        </div>
        
        {
          /** 'total' is the result of multiplying the two previous fields. 
          *   It only updates the form data when it get the focus.
          */
         }
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="total">Total: </label>
          <input type="number"
            {...register("total")}
            value={watch('price') * watch('quantity')}
            readOnly
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value='Submit' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I was expecting the form state to update regardless of whether or not the "total" field got focus.

Thanks in advance everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** You would need to `watch` the fields as well, to get their values in the app:

```
const price = watch("price") 
const quantity = watch("quantity")
```

---

It might be easier for you to use `setValue` combined with `useEffect`:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch, setValue } = useForm({ 
  defaultValues: { price: 0, quantity: 0, total: 0 } 
});

...

useEffect(() => {
  setValue('total', quantity * price)
}, [quantity, price])

...

  <input type="number"
    {...register("total")} // No need to watch        
    readOnly
  />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to add two lines of code to your example because it was throwing me the error "variable_name" not defined. I ended up watching price and quantity   but that is ok, it solves my problem.

Comment: @SANDROSIMON Yes, I missed the `watch` part.. glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Thank you @Anurag Srivastava (sorry I'm not allowed to vote yet).  This is the final code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

function App() {

  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
      total: 0
    }
  });

  // I had to add these two lines
  const price = watch("price") 
  const quantity = watch("quantity")

  useEffect( ()=> {
    setValue('total', price * quantity)
  }, [price, quantity, setValue])

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="quantity">Quantity: </label>
          <input type="number" 
            {...register("quantity")}  
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="price">Price: </label>
          <input type="number"
            {...register("price")}
          />
        </div>
        
        {
          /** 'total' is the result of multiplying the two previous fields. 
          *   It only updates the form data when it get the focus.
          */
         }
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="total">Total: </label>
          <input type="number"
            {...register("total")}
            //value={watch('price') * watch('quantity')}
            readOnly
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value='Submit' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```